# How to make calendar using tktinker

Tags: python, tkinter

csn u give me ideas how i can make a calendar using tkinter. The calendar should be customizable, you can add or schedule your events like the calendar installed in our phone. I really have no idea what to do next.

Comment: first learn `python` and `tkinter`. Your idea is very complex - you will have to create all from scratch. And first try to display few numbers in row and columns using `.grid()` before you try to create callendar.

Comment: BTW: for calendar you will have to know in which day starts month (monday, thusday, etc.) and how many days it has, and if it is leap year.

Comment: [tkcalendar](https://pypi.org/project/tkcalendar/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's sample code i found for a tkinter calendar:

```
import calendar as cd
import tkinter as tk

# supply year and month
year = 2007
month = 2    # jan=1

# assign the month's calendar to a multiline string
str1 = cd.month(year, month)

# create the window form and call it root (typical)
root = tk.Tk()
root.title("Monthly Calendar")

# pick a fixed font like courier so spaces behave right 
label1 = tk.Label(root, text=str1, font=('courier', 14, 'bold'), bg='yellow')
label1.pack(padx=3, pady=5)

# run the event loop (needed)
root.mainloop()
```